# I got error PlatformNotSupportedException when I work with date's

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I work on windows-mobile 6.5

the region is `English (United States)` date: `M/d/yy` time: `h:mm:ss tt`

I've this code:

```
DateTime dt_1,dt_2;
try
    {
         CultureInfo obj = new CultureInfo("en-US");
         dt_1 = DateTime.Parse(TmpD_from, obj);
    }
catch
    {
          CultureInfo obj = new CultureInfo("he-IL");
          dt_1 = DateTime.Parse(TmpD_from, obj);
    }

try
    {
          CultureInfo obj = new CultureInfo("en-US");
          dt_2 = DateTime.Parse(TmpD_to, obj);
    }
catch
    {
          CultureInfo obj = new CultureInfo("he-IL");
          dt_2 = DateTime.Parse(TmpD_to, obj);
    }

if (DateTime.Today >= dt_1.Date && DateTime.Today <= dt_2.Date)
    {
          return true;
    }
else
    {
           return false;
    }
```

the values:

```
TmpD_to:   31/12/2011 00:00:00
TmpD_from: 31/12/2011 00:00:00
```

and I got this error: `PlatformNotSupportedException`

Comment: *Where* did you get that error? By the way, your last 8 lines are equivalent to just `return DateTime.Today >= dt_1.Date && DateTime.Today <= dt_2.Date;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably get the Exception because the culture "he-IL" (Hebrew, right?) is not supported by Windows Mobile 6.5. I would suggest trying another culture, whose formatting results are close (or equal) to what you want.