# Got a PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: asp.net

Suddenly while i try to run my web application I got this:

> PlatformNotSupportedException Error

I mentioned the Exception details below:

> [PlatformNotSupportedException: This operation requires IIS integrated
>   pipeline mode.]    System.Web.HttpResponse.get_Headers() +9710022
>   System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.get_Headers() +9
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders..ctor(HttpResponseBase
>   response) +72
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.CreateEnvironment() +434
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.GetInitialEnvironment(HttpApplication
>   application) +303
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.PrepareInitialContext(HttpApplication
>   application) +65
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.BeginEvent(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extradata) +622
>   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +285    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [I got error PlatformNotSupportedException when I work with date's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606810/i-got-error-platformnotsupportedexception-when-i-work-with-dates)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313167/this-operation-requires-iis-integrated-pipeline-mode)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer for the issue my self..

Go into Project properties. Select Web Tab. Select "Use Local IIS Web server" Check "Use IIS Express"

This will solve the issue.

Comment: Issue will appears again on production mode when publish to IIS.